# How to Pass datetime params to HttpGet in web api 2.0?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api2

I have a Get API , where I am getting results based on two datetime params(startdate and enddate) , but while passing datetime I am getting error saying "Potential dangerous.....etc). I have to pass compulsory datetime as mandatory from URL. do you have any solutions on this ?

Regards,
Rajnesh.

Comment: In what format are you passing the dates? We've got no code and no example data, and not even a full output of an error message, so we can only guess what your problem is. My advice is to make sure you use an unambiguous format with no special characters, such as ISO8601

Comment: c# datetime and format is 2016-01-01T10:12:05.254Z as this input i am getting from UI team as they are calling web api to get the reports data between those 2 months.

Code : [Route("{userId}/weathercondition/{fromDate}/{toDate}/{speciesId:int}", Name = "GetReports")]




 public HttpResponseMessage GetTopWeatherCondition([FromUri]string userId, [FromUri] string fromDate, [FromUri]string toDate)






Error : A potentially dangerous Request.Path value was detected from the client

Comment: Please use the "edit" button to add information to your question. Code in comments is hard to read. Please give us a sample of the full URL being generated as well.

Answer (score 0):

WEB APIs consider colon (:) as dangerous. Try passing date in yyyy-mm-ddThh-mm-ss format. If u own the both client and server ends than i suggest you to use unix timestamps for this.